# propagate workflow changes into all branches/tags automatically

Tags: github, github-actions

I currently have the issue that I got existing tags and feature branches, relying on several `workflow.yaml` files to build/deploy/etc.

Whenever I do a change on any workflow via the default branch, I also need to pull these changes into every other branch.
Otherwise, the deployment of an existing branch fails or doesn't have those changes of the workflows.
That isn't the biggest issue though.

The biggest issue I got is for tags, because I don't want to modify existing tags.

Is there any solution or workaround to this?

Comment: Why the tags are a major concern in this scenario? Why would you need to modify them? Could you please elaborate on that a bit?

Comment: For updating the branches you will need to update them after pushing changes into the default branch. Either rebase (recommended) or cherry pick your changes into all other branches. If you want to automate that, write a script that does it and trigger it from the default branch. Additionally: what did you already try and what issues did you run into?